# Calculating rollsum and Delt with offsets

Tags: r, rolling-computation, delta

I have df `a` which has two columns viz; PC and Price as given below

```
dput(a)

structure(list(PC = c(0, -0.009, 0, -0.008, 0.003, 0.008, -0.017, 
0.032, 0.062, -0.02), Price = c(111.449554, 110.495506, 110.476242, 
109.560745, 109.859482, 110.68824, 108.780159, 112.239769, 119.216805, 
116.826897)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I have `lookbackPeriod = 2` which means I have to calculate `rollsum` of `a$PC` column for every nth `lookbackPeriod` and

this I could calculate by

```
 b <- data.frame(MScore = rollsum(a$PC,k=lookbackPeriod ))
```

I also have `holdPeriod = 2` which means I have to calculate percentage in price for every nth `holdPeriod` but nth `holdPeriod` period starts where the nth `lookbackPeriod` ends

example if this was `a` then for the rollsum it will consider values in Yellow but to calculate percentage change it will consider value in orange and green.

[image]

So final output in B would look line this for the given input

The output will have `nrow(a) - lookbackPeriod + 1 - holdPeriod` observations

[image]

This kind of gives me the results but it is coercing LHS to list at the last line and first two records of Delt function result have NA

```
b <- data.frame(MScore = rollsum(a$PC,k=lookbackPeriod ))
b <- b[1:(nrow(b)-holdPeriod+1),]
a <- a[lookbackPeriod:nrow(a),]
b$PChg <- as.data.frame( Delt(a$Price,k=holdPeriod))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rollapply` with a width equal to the sum of the periods left aligning the results using the appropriate functions:

```
library(zoo)

k1 <- lookbackPeriod
k <- k1 + holdPeriod
roll <- function(...) rollapply(..., fill = NA, align = "left")
transform(a, MScore = roll(PC, k, function(x) sum(x[1:k1])),
             PChg = roll(Price, k, function(x) x[k]/x[k1]-1))
```

giving:

```
       PC    Price MScore         PChg
1   0.000 111.4496 -0.009 -0.008459720
2  -0.009 110.4955 -0.009 -0.005582739
3   0.000 110.4762 -0.008  0.010291049
4  -0.008 109.5607 -0.005 -0.009824578
5   0.003 109.8595  0.011  0.014017108
6   0.008 110.6882 -0.009  0.095942551
7  -0.017 108.7802  0.015  0.040869008
8   0.032 112.2398     NA           NA
9   0.062 119.2168     NA           NA
10 -0.020 116.8269     NA           NA
```

This variation would also work:

```
f <- function(x) c(MScore = sum(x[1:k1, 1]), PChg = x[k, 2]/x[k1, 2] - 1)
cbind(a, rollapply(a, k, f, fill = NA, align = "left", by.column = FALSE))
```